# Data Not Inserted in One of the table SQLite

Tags: android, sql, database, multiple-columns

In my application i need two tables of dataBase with difrrent data except for "TAGS".
i have a `"days table"` and `"setting table"` i just want add to the tables data without create a new DBhandler.

here is my code ? what i'm doing wrong?? please help me...

DbHandler:

```
public class DbHandler  {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "myShifts.db";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_DAYS = "days";
    public static final String TABLE_SETTING = "setting";

    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String TAGS = "tags";

    //DATE
    public static final String DATE_DAY = "day";
    public static final String DATE_MONTH = "month";
    public static final String DATE_YEAR = "year"; 


    //SETTING
    public static final String BASIC_HOUR = "basicHour";
    public static final String BASIC_SEC = "basicSec";
    public static final String EXTRA0 = "extra0";
    public static final String EXTRA1 = "extra1";
    public static final String EXTRA2 = "extra2";



    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DAYS = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_DAY + "(" 
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + TAGS + " TEXT,"
            + DATE_DAY + " INTEGER,"
            + DATE_MONTH + " INTEGER,"
            + DATE_YEAR + " INTEGER)";


    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SETTING = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_SETTING + "(" 
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + TAGS   + " TEXT,"
            + BASIC_HOUR + " INTEGER,"
            + BASIC_SEC + " INTEGER,"
            + EXTRA0 + " REAL,"
            + EXTRA1 + " REAL,"
            + EXTRA2 + " REAL)";



    DbHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase myDb;
    Context context;

    public DbHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        helper = new DbHelper(context);
    }

    public DbHandler open(){
        myDb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        helper.close();
    }


//INSERT TO DAY TABLE
    public void addDay(Clock clock){
        try {
            open();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(WORK_NAME, clock.getWorkName());
            cv.put(DATE_DAY, clock.getDateDay());
            cv.put(DATE_MONTH, clock.getDateMonth());
            cv.put(DATE_YEAR, clock.getDateYear());

            myDb.insert(TABLE_DAYS, null, cv); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally{
            close();
        }


    }


        //GET FROM DAY TABLE
    public ArrayList<Clock> getDay(String byTag){
        try {
            open();
            ArrayList<Clock> list = new ArrayList<Clock>();
            Cursor c = null;
            c = myDb.query(TABLE_DAY, null,"tags = ?", new String[] {byTag}, null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Clock clock = new Clock(
                        c.getInt(0),
                        c.getString(1),
                        c.getInt(2), 
                        c.getInt(3),
                        c.getInt(4),
                        c.getInt(5));

                list.add(clock);        
            }       
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }finally{
            close();
        }
    }




    //ADD TO SETTING TABLE
    public void addSetting(Clock clock){
        try {
            open();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TAGS, clock.getWorkName());
            cv.put(BASIC_HOUR, clock.getBasicHour());
            cv.put(BASIC_SEC, clock.getBasicSec());
            cv.put(EXTRA0, clock.getExtra0());
            cv.put(EXTRA1, clock.getExtra1());
            cv.put(EXTRA2, clock.getExtra2());

            myDb.insert(TABLE_SETTING, null, cv); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally{
            close();
        }


    }

//GET FROM SETTING TABLE
    public ArrayList<Clock> getSetting(String byTags){
        try {
            open();
            ArrayList<Clock> list = new ArrayList<Clock>();

            Cursor c = myDb.query(TABLE_SETTING, null,"tags= ?", new String[] {byTags}, null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Clock clock = new Clock(
                        c.getInt(0),
                        c.getString(1),
                        c.getFloat(2), 
                        c.getFloat(3),
                        c.getInt(4),
                        c.getInt(5), 
                        c.getInt(6));


                list.add(clock);        
            }       
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }finally{
            close();
        }
    }








    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DAYS);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SETTING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_DAY);      
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_SETTING);      
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

my Clock.class:

```
public class Clock {

    protected  int id = 0;
    protected  String tags;
    protected  int dateDay;
    protected  int dateMonth;
    protected int dateYear;

    protected  int basicHour ; 
    protected  int basicSec ;  
    protected   float extra0 ; 
    protected  float  extra1; 
    protected  float extra2 ; 

    //the constructor for table 1
    public Clock(int id, String tags, int dateDay, int dateMonth, int dateYear,
            int basicHour) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.dateDay = dateDay;
        this.dateMonth = dateMonth;
        this.dateYear = dateYear;
        this.basicHour = basicHour;
    }
    //the constructor for table 2
    public Clock(int id, String tags, int basicHour, int basicSec,
            float extra0, float extra1, float extra2) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.basicHour = basicHour;
        this.basicSec = basicSec;
        this.extra0 = extra0;
        this.extra1 = extra1;
        this.extra2 = extra2;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
    public int getDateDay() {
        return dateDay;
    }
    public void setDateDay(int dateDay) {
        this.dateDay = dateDay;
    }
    public int getDateMonth() {
        return dateMonth;
    }
    public void setDateMonth(int dateMonth) {
        this.dateMonth = dateMonth;
    }
    public int getDateYear() {
        return dateYear;
    }
    public void setDateYear(int dateYear) {
        this.dateYear = dateYear;
    }
    public int getBasicHour() {
        return basicHour;
    }
    public void setBasicHour(int basicHour) {
        this.basicHour = basicHour;
    }
    public int getBasicSec() {
        return basicSec;
    }
    public void setBasicSec(int basicSec) {
        this.basicSec = basicSec;
    }
    public float getExtra0() {
        return extra0;
    }
    public void setExtra0(float extra0) {
        this.extra0 = extra0;
    }
    public float getExtra1() {
        return extra1;
    }
    public void setExtra1(float extra1) {
        this.extra1 = extra1;
    }
    public float getExtra2() {
        return extra2;
    }
    public void setExtra2(float extra2) {
        this.extra2 = extra2;
    }
```

works only if i pass a one specific String:

```
DbHandler hand = new DbHandler(this);
hand.addSetting("setting");

hand.addDay("setting");
```

Comment: What is a multiply table?

Comment: it's mean i have two tables or more on one database file

Comment: Change `db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_WORKs);` to `db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DAYS);`

Comment: Sorry..It was a mistake, that I simplified the code to the question. But that's not my code error. i fix my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I think ID is not auto incremented that is why it is not inserting in the database so add this into your table query string just like mentioned below

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DAYS = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_DAY + "(" 
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," 
            + TAGS + " TEXT,"
            + DATE_DAY + " INTEGER,"
            + DATE_MONTH + " INTEGER,"
            + DATE_YEAR + " INTEGER)";


    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SETTING = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_SETTING + "(" 
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," 
            + TAGS   + " TEXT,"
            + BASIC_HOUR + " INTEGER,"
            + BASIC_SEC + " INTEGER,"
            + EXTRA0 + " REAL,"
            + EXTRA1 + " REAL,"
            + EXTRA2 + " REAL)";
```

also see this example.

```
   public class SessionDescriptionsDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
```

Fields for first table

```
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final String TABLE_SESSIONDESCRIPTIONS = "session_descriptions";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
```

Fields for second table

```
    private static final String TABLE_SESSIONLEADERS = "session_leaders";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "category";
    private static final String COLUMN_ORGANIZATION = "summary";
    private static final String COLUMN_PICURL = "google";
```

constructor

```
    public SessionDescriptionsDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

first table creation string

```
  public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1 = "create table "
                    + TABLE_SESSIONDESCRIPTIONS
                    + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
                    + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null"
                    + ");";
```

second table creation string

```
       public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE2 = "create table "
                + TABLE_SESSIONLEADERS
                + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_ORGANIZATION + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_PICURL + " text not null"
                + ");";
```

tables creation SQL statement on OnCreate() Method

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1); // first table creation
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE2); // second table creation

    }
```

Comment: You should add an explanation, rather than just providing code.

Comment: It's great ! but my code create two tables perfectly. but i can't inserting to "SETTING_TABLE" nothing...

Comment: have you done step debugging the method of addSetting(Clock clock) ?

Comment: i tried to add String value Instead Clock class i made with the variables. and it suddenly working!! but why with my Clock class it doesn't? i edited my question and add the "Clock" class please Take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59618/discussion-between-softcoder-and-matt).